# Help on the derivation rules of the Big Theta notation

Tags: asymptotics

I'm really confused about the operation rules of the Big Theta notation. For example, I have met the following derivation process:

$$
cos(\theta_r(y))=1+2(e^{-2y}+e^{-2r}-e^{R-r-y}-e^{-R-r-y})(1+\Theta(e^{-2r}))(1+\Theta(e^{-2y}))
= 1-2e^{R-r-y}+\Theta(e^{-2y}+e^{-2r})
$$
The derivation is performed by the use of condition $y\ge R-r$.

Can anyone give me some tips on this derivation step ? How can it come to the second expression ?

Thanks!